# User Input Security .net

Tags: asp.net, security, json

I have clientside user-settings manager. the settings are saved through a webservice. I´m serializing them into json. Since the json can be manipulated before sending, I want to validate it on server then.

What are the best practices, what have i to look for?
Validating before deserialization? What kind of malicious input can the user use? Can he manipulate the json so that it harms me somehow on deserialization using default asp net javascript deserialization?

```
var userinput = { param1 : "test", categories : ["2312", "4324", "2122"] }
```

this one is sent to the server, serialized.
Deserialized on server into an object graph.

```
public class usersettings
 public property param1 as string
 public property categories as string()
end class
```

param1 is regex checked, maybe only letters and digits, start with letter, maximum 10 signs, for example.
categories must be distinct, not more than 10...

the usersettingsclass is a linq to sql genereted object, that can be directly pushed to the sqlserver.

this is all a very simple sample. in the userinput can be anything.

Comment: Other than the predicament regarding dangers of deserialization, you'll probably need to be more specific in terms of your environment and so on; +1 for the question.

Comment: depends on how complicated and secure you need it to be? what about using oauth? http://oauth.net/

Comment: A lot depends on your deserialization library.

Answer (score 0):

Are these settings security sensitive? What happens if the user messes with them?

If the only thing that happens is you can an exception, then don't bother.

If these settings can somehow compromise security, then they shouldn't be client side unless they're encrypted **by the server** before they're sent down to the client. In other words, they're "on the client" for scalability reasons only, not because they're manipulated in any way by the client.

If these settings are security sensitive, *and* they must be modifiable by the client, they you have an untenable situation. If javascript can modify them, so can the user.

Lastly, if all your'e worried about is that the client somehow manipulates the json data so that it causes a deserialization exception, you should research if there are any vulnerabilities in your json library. If not, don't worry about it until they're are.

Since you mentioned you're using built-in ASP.NET libraries, I can say that I'm unaware of any known vulernability in these libs.

Comment: I´m just using this settings to enable the user to manipulate his own presentation profile. But I have some rules, like that the navigation menu on left, must be the first element there, and may be only once there. The user can say, out of 10 navigation items, to show these 10 or only 2, but 2 are minimum. 
I´m now checking on Server, parsing the json into an object, using some value checkers, allowing only propertynames that are allowed, and passing only types that are allowed. Mostly a use only booleans, integers and basic strings. One little misstake and no action is performed.